# modifying elements list of tuples python

Tags: python

As I know a tuple is immutable structure, so if I have a list of tuples.

```
list1 = [(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5)]
```

and I have to change the first element of a tuple then I will have to basically
write:

```
list1[0] = (2,2,3,4)     not list1[0][0] = 2 because tuple is immutable
```

For each element I need to do this. Is this an efficient operation or is it better to use a list of lists if this operation needs to be done regularly?

Comment: Actually even with a list of tuples you still can not change the tuple. You'd better use a list of lists.

Comment: Yes I know but you can always reassign the first element of the list which is the tuple to a new tuple like I have done above. I don't know how efficient it is.

Comment: If you need to do this for each element of your list, then use a list of lists.

Comment: Sukrit,  is it more efficient to use a list of lists than to reassign one element of the list (which is a tuple) like list1[0] = (2,2,3,4) even when I know that the element is four dimensional? Won't list waste memory and tuple will be more efficient?

Comment: If you're asking about efficiency, the answer is to profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to modify the elements of the list, then use mutable elements. Storing an immutable object in a mutable container does not make the object mutable.

As for efficiency, constructing a new tuple is more expensive than modifying a list. But readability is more important than runtime performance for most operations, so optimize for readability first. Also keep in mind that when the elements of a list of lists are referenced from the outside, you might get side-effects:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

lol = [l1, l2]
lol[0][0] = 0

print(l1)  # prints [0, 2, 3]
```

**UPDATE**: to back my claim of efficiency, here's some timings using IPython's `%timeit` magic:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1,2,3,4] for _ in xrange(10000)]
>>> list_of_tuples = map(tuple, list_of_lists)
>>> def modify_lol():
...     for x in list_of_lists:
...         x[0] = 0
...         
>>> def modify_lot():
...     for i, x in enumerate(list_of_tuples):
...         list_of_tuples[i] = (0,) + x[1:]
...         
>>> %timeit modify_lol()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.56 ms per loop
>>> %timeit modify_lot()
100 loops, best of 3: 17 ms per loop
```

So lists of lists are 2.6× faster for this task.

Comment: Is it more efficient to use a list of lists than to reassign one element of the list (which is a tuple) like list1[0] = (2,2,3,4) even when I know that the element is four dimensional? Won't list waste memory and tuple will be more efficient??

Comment: @vkaul11: lists may take a little more memory. But are you processing large amounts of data? I.e. will you actually notice the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at the direct solution you have the equivalent of

```
list[0] = (2,) + list[0] [1:]
```

Which should be enough to allow you to do it programmatically. It's still making a copy, but that's fairly quick, as is slicing the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your variable like that:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]
```

You will able to change the value of an elemento of a list like that:

```
list1[0][0] = 2
```

Now your variable value will be:

```
list1 = [[2,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The inefficently will come when you have to change ONLY a specific element. For instance say you had two tuples.

```
tup1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
tup2 = (5, 6, 7, 8)
```

And you wanted to change the first element of both tuples to 9.

```
tup1 = (9, 2, 3, 4)
tup2 = (9, 6, 7, 8)
```

Is the only way to do that, if you had a million tuples with different values that all needed to start with 9 then this way is obviously inefficent, you will have to type and reassign all tuples different values.

Instead you should use a list.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Then you can do

```
list = [l1, l2]
for l in list:
    l[0] = 9
```

Which will change all the first elements to 9 without hardcoding a million lists.

`l1` is now `[9, 2, 3, 4]`

`l2` is now `[9, 6, 7, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

```
L = [(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5)]
L = [tuple([2]+subL[1:]) for subL in L]
```

This is slower, as it has to recreate all those tuples.

OR

```
L = [(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5)]
L = [list(i) for i in L] # or L = map(list, L)
for subL in L:
    subL[0] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll only ever have four elements in your list items, but they need to be mutable, the best option (in my opinion) is to use a class:

```
class WXYZ: # example name, give yours something more sensible to the nature of the code
    def __init__(self, w=0, x=0, y=0, z=0)
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Then your code will look something like:

```
list1 = [WXYZ(1,2,3,4), WXYZ(2,3,4,5)]
list1[0].w = 2
```

You can also easily add an `__iter__` method if you need to use it in a `for` loop:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((w,x,y,z))
```

Alternatively, if you want to get clever, you can do

```
    def __iter__(self):
        yield w
        yield x
        yield y
        yield z
```

If you're *really* worried about memory usage (why are you using python in that case?), you can define `__slots__ = ("w","x","y","z")` to assign exactly as much memory as is required.